# Facebook Login Issue in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developing an iOS application which uses Facebook as one of the mode for user login. I have added the code as this:

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    if error != nil { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    if result.isCancelled{
        print("Cancelled") }
    else {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("facebookLogin", sender: self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
    fbLoginButton.center = view.center

    //checking current login status
    checkCurrentLoginStatus()

    fbLoginButton.delegate = self


}

func checkCurrentLoginStatus(){
    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil{
        //load data from here
    }
    else {
        print("Not yet logged in!")
    }
}
```

and the basic code in app delegate file along with permissions in info plist. I am not sure but currently but for some reason when I am trying authorise app in safari web browser, web view goes blank with the done button. If someone can tell me why is this happening, it will be really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Close all the tabs in your safari (in simulator or device) .Remove the app and the derived data . try running the app again .

Comment: Nah! On bit of code change it allows me to go to the main screens of code which I am doing through segue but I still have to manually press done button on safari to do so. It might be the default behaviour but I am not sure :(

Answer (score 0):

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewControllerStoryboardIdhere") as! FirstViewControllerClassnamehere
```

This solved it. :)